# Splitting datetime index to identify consecutive timestamps (Python)

Tags: python, numpy, split

I know there are several posts on how to split series based on consecutive values, and I have adopted some of their code, but I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

I have a long datetimeindex ("times" below), and I want to split it to identify consecutive groupings. So, every time there is a gap in time longer than the normal time increment, I want it to split. The index is evenly incremented (10m between times).

```
times = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq=frequency).difference(x.index)

splits = ((times-pd.Series(times).shift(-1)).abs() != frequency)

consec = np.split(times, splits)
```

"Splits" is a boolean array that accurately indicates where the splits should occur, so that seems to be working correctly.

However, when I actually use np.split, instead of splitting into sections, the output is like this, where it is only keeping the values that are at the split indices:

```
[DatetimeIndex([], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None), DatetimeIndex(['2003-02-05 09:20:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None), DatetimeIndex([], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None), DatetimeIndex([], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None), DatetimeIndex([], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None), DatetimeIndex([], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None), DatetimeIndex([], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None), DatetimeIndex(['2003-02-09 01:20:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None), DatetimeIndex([], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None), DatetimeIndex([], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None), DatetimeIndex([], .... etc
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

indices_or_sections argument of np.split accepts an array of integers.
To get it from split (an array of bools) you can use np.where:

```
splits_indexes = np.where(splits)
```

Then you can call

```
consec = np.split(times, splits_indexes + 1)
```

The +1 is there to identify the beginning of a new part.